# nlmer error: Error in initializePtr() : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

Tags: r, runtime-error, lme4, non-linear-regression

I have repeated measures data examining forest `Biomass` across forest `Age` for multiple `Plots`:

In other words: `Biomass ~ Age | Plot`

```
#Reproducible Example data:

biom.dat <- c(unlist(lapply(1:7, function(x){ set.seed(x) ; sort(sample(2:500,15))})),
  unlist(lapply(8:15, function(x){ set.seed(x) ;  c(sort(sample(2:500,12)),(sample(90:500,3)))})))
dat <- data.frame(Plot = rep(1:5,each = 15), Age = rep(c((1:75)[(1:5)%%5 == 0])+8,5), Biomass = biom.dat)

> head(dat)
  Plot Age Biomass
1    1  13      32
2    1  18      88
3    1  23     101
4    1  28     102
5    1  33     134
6    1  38     187
```

I tried using `nlmer` to examine a non-linear trend in this data. I use `nlmer`  so I incorporate the `Plot` structure as a random effect.

I'm trying to run an extension of the model seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50182884/4581200) that uses this custom function:

[image]

which I've coded in R as:

```
function(Age,C,Ao,s,wd,ph) C + Ao * exp(-s*Age) * cos(wd*Age + ph)
```

However, when I run the `nlmer` code (see below), **I get the following error**:

```
Error in initializePtr() : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

[This discussion](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/173) suggested to me that I might have a scaling problem? (which was hinted at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184567/4581200)).

So I tried scaling the variables (1st just the `Age` predictor, but then also the `Biomass` response). Even after scaling both variables, I still get the same error...

**Questions:**

1. What else could be going wrong?  (What else should I check?)
2. Where do I go from here?

---

**My Code:**

**Update:** Based on deleted @42 comments, I've adjusted the code (originally inspired by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868452/4581200)) to more closely match code from the `nlmer` [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-17/topics/nlmer) (Example #3):  `[Note: the errors still occur]`

```
  #Create equation:
    LTI.eqn <- ~ C + Ao * exp(-s*Age) * cos(wd * Age + ph)

  #Build function (incorporating a "gradient" attribute in the formula using deriv():
    LTI.func <- deriv(LTI.eqn, namevec = c('C', 'Ao', 's', 'wd', 'ph'),
                  function.arg = c('Age', 'C', 'Ao', 's', 'wd', 'ph'))

  #Load package:  
    library(lme4)

  #Create named vector of starting values for my constants:
    nlmer.start <- c(C = 0,Ao = -1,s = 1,wd = 1,ph = 0)

  #Run model:
    nlmer(Biomass ~ LTI.func(Age, C, Ao, s, wd, ph) ~ (Age | Plot), 
          data = dat, start=nlmer.start)

     #Error in initializePtr() : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

  #So let's rescale the continuous predictor variables (in this case we'll center Age):
    nlmer(Biomass ~ LTI.func(Age, C, Ao, s, wd, ph) ~ (Age | Plot), 
          data = transform(dat,Age = Age - 51), start = nlmer.start)

     #Error in initializePtr() : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

  #Still a problem. What if I scale Biomass, too???
    datt <- transform(dat,Age = (Age - 51), Biomass = scale(Biomass, center = F))
    nlmer(Biomass ~ LTI.func(Age, C, Ao, s, wd, ph) ~ (Age | Plot),
          data = datt, start = nlmer.start)

     #Error in initializePtr() : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

Comment: I chose `nlmer` vs `nlme` because I have numerous other models already generated using `lme4` to compare to (of course, using REML = F)

Comment: I'm not sure I should be commenting further and don't really have the experience to certify an answer but perhaps following BenBolker's advice here:   http://rpubs.com/bbolker/3423 . I'll delete my earlier comments to make room for other contributions.

Comment: @42 thanks for your time and comments! Just FYI, I've adjusted the function and still get the same errors. I'll check out your Bolker link to see if it'll help. Thanks!

Comment: @42 I tried Ben's `tmpstr <- deparse(` approach from the [link you shared](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/3423). Unfortunately, although it definitely changed the function call, it did nothing to alleviate the cause of the error. Thanks though!